# How can I run a "headless" (no GUI) Unity3D game inside a C# program?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to execute only the model part of a game, without a GUI of any sort.

As such, I would instantiate some classes from Unity3D, arrange them somehow, "start" them whatever that means, and periodically read the state of the components inside the game, or else receive update events from them.

Currently I have already the [Unity DLLs available with a NuGet Package](http://precisionmojo.github.io/Unity3D.DLLs/), but I don't know how to go on from here:

```
public class HelloUnity3D
{
    void run()
    {
        var myGame = new UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour();

        //myGame.WhatNow(?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible.

AFAIK, `MonoBehaviour` is executed by the editor or players (playback engine) of Unity3D-you can find them in *unity3d_install_dir\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines* on Windows.

So if you want to "execute only the model part of a game", you have to write a modeling-only playback engine. But I don't think that can be done without access to source code of Unity3D.

But it's possible to run `MonoBehaviour` codes that doesn't run code that requires Unity3D playback engines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I am most interested in physics (gravity, collision detection, etc.). Do you think I can create some sort of scene, and update it manually from a hand-made game loop?

Comment: Yes. Just do it inside the Unity editor. See [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html). There are many tutorials on physics with Unity3D. You may be also interested in [existing physics-related projects on the asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=2/sortby=relevance/query=physics).